# write XML subtree to file

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

so I have a huge XML file but only want a portion of it in another file. hence I want to extract it and then I can do some work on it without affecting the original file.

here is the basic idea

```
<a>
      <otherethings> </otherthings>
      <b>
          <things> </thing>
      </b>
      <otherethings2></otherthings2>
</a>
```

Simply put I want to extract b to another file and edit it

how can this be accomplished in python

I am currently trying to use `xml.etree.ElementTree`

but can't seem to get it right.

as requested my mistakes

1.

```
    tree = ET.parse('Data.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    rootelement = root.iter('b')
    tree._setroot(rootelement)
    root = tree.getroot()
    tree.write('Data2.xml')
```

2.

```
tree = ET.parse('Data.xml', 'b')
root = tree.getroot()
tree.write('Data2.xml')
```

In all honesty I was simply guessing

don't get me wrong, I did look online but could not find anything.

Comment: Can you post you code?

Comment: I all honestly I don't think it will help because it is completely not working but i tried several things. here are a couple.

Comment: Take a look at these links: http://lxml.de/ (which is simelar but better than elementtree) or http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ My personal favourite, because its really easy to use

Answer (score 2):

this should work.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Data.xml')
for el in tree.iter('b'):
    towrite = ET.ElementTree(el)
    towrite.write('Data2.xml')
```